# How to access GAE application through multiple custom domains over HTTPS with single UC/SAN certificate?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, ssl-certificate

we have following situation:

- we have an application on Google App Engine (GAE)
- we want to be able to access this application from 3 different custom URLs through HTTPS. (let's say a.com, b.com, c.com)
- we have Unified communiction (UC/SAN) SSL certificate for those three domains
- for accessing GAE applications through custom HTTPS URLs, GAE requires to have Google Apps for Work account.
- only **primary domains** of Goole Apps for Work accounts can be used for accessing GAE applications through custom domains over HTTPS. [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#about_using_app_engine_with_google_apps)
- so we've created 3 Google Apps for Work accounts
- now when I log in to admin.google.com for a.com and try to upload our SSL UC/SAN certificate covering our 3 domains, I get a message "The SSL certificate references subdomain outside of managed domain.". I infer that it comes from [requirement](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#certificate_requirements)

> All subject names on the host certificate should match or be subdomains of the domains associated with the account in the Google Apps Control Panel.
>   
>   How can this be resolved ?

Is it **possible at all** to access one GAE application through multiple custom domains over HTTPS by using one certificate ? Or do we have to get separate certificate for each custom domain?

Answer (score 0):

From Google's docs it looks like they do support SAN [1], however it seems only in the case of subdomains. Since you have a Google Apps for Work account, you have access to technical support (admin.google.com -> Support) and this seems like it would be a good question for them (ie. "Can I use a SAN cert with multiple second-level domains with Google Apps, or is it subdomain only?").

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Comment: I've asked already and they say that it's GAE problem and that it's outside of scope of their support. I can try to rephrase it and ask again .. :(

Comment: Further, the question is more specific. It's not only whether SAN cert can be used for multiple second-level domains with Google Apps, but whether it can be used for multiple **primary domains** from other Google Apps accounts.

Comment: FYI: Google Apps for Work support reconfirms that it's not their business and thus do not provide support for this topic.

Comment: Too bad. I assume that in your case it won't work as everything is mapped through Google Apps, and they have a one primary domain restriction per Apps account (you can only map your primary domain to your GAE app). Making one SNI cert work across multiple Google Apps accounts doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: yop, it doesn't work :(
i've even tried using an alias for a primary domain, but it didn't work either.